# How is the initial value of the stack pointer determined?

Tags: linux, memory, 64-bit, stack

The program loader initializes/loads the `text`, `data+bss` areas. These are allocated in the process' virtual address space near the beginning. The heap would then grow (after data+bss) towards larger addresses. The stack grows from something large towards lower addresses.

I wonder how the initial value of the stack pointer is determined.

If I ask for the virtual address limit per process (`ulimit -v`) I get

```
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Now, this `unlimited` certainly refers to the technical limits put by a finite number of bits available for addressing (on 64 bit Linux I recall 48 bits?!)

So, is it that simple that unless a different `ulimit` applies the stack pointer is roughly initialized to (start of vmem + 2^48 bits)?

Comment: In some systems, the SP is initialized with 0 since `push` would decrement the address first and then write to the memory. But I don't know what algorithm Linux uses right now. Also, for security reasons, the address of the stack pointer is probably not fixed anymore.

Comment: When decrementing zero you get an `int` underflow which rolls back to maximum `int` number. This is how the systems you are talking of determine how far away the stack pointer is from the beginning. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: @Frank: you would get an underflow of the appropriate type. For a 64 bit pointer that's different from a 32 bit `int`.

Comment: Yes sure, an `int` doesn't underflow at 0. I meant an `uint` or `size_t` equivalent in C. On 64bit it unsigned long.

Comment: @Frank: Yes. The CPU architecture will make sure you get the largest possible address. The VM tables will then map this virtual address to some page in real memory.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Why does this VM mapping work at the end of the address space, i.e. for stack, but not "in the middle" of the address space?? E.g. poking around in heap space without prior `valloc` gives a segfault

Comment: How do you plan to poke in your stack before the kernel even started your process? Before giving you the stack pointer, the kernel must set up the top of the stack, for example, it will dump all the CPU registers there so your process can "restore" them when it first gets woken.

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly platform dependent question, and depends on the bit-ness of the program you are running, the operating system version in use, system configuration options, whether or not the program is single or multi-threaded, and other factors:

- For modern Linux systems the initial stack base for single threaded programs is controlled by the kernel [Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).
- In the ancient days before ASLR I think the main thread's stack used to be at a high fixed address for 32-bit Linux.  For 64-bit before ASLR (or if you disable it), it was probably at a fixed address somewhere well away from everything else, but I wouldn't be surprised if that address was kernel version dependent.
- For multi-threaded Linux programs the stack is allocated using mmap by glibc before the clone() call that starts the thread (see: [nptl/allocatestack.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/allocatestack.c))
- On 32-bit single threaded AIX the stack and heap (sbrk controlled) used to co-exist in one of the 16 256 mb segments (I forget which one.)  I recall there was lots of *fun* to be had for all if you compiled with options that allowed the stack to grow into heap.
- ...